# I'm trying to bake a cloth simulation, but I can't find the "pc2" option so I can't bake it

Tags: export, baking, cloth-simulation

The option for Pointcache/ pc2 can nowhere be found.

[image: Where is the pc2 option!?!?!?]

Answer (score 3):

just enable the add-on, then you can export it:

[image]